# How to make second python x-axis with non ordered values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I would like to have the axes2 axis showing values from the distance vector the way they are in the vector, and not to be order increasingly like it is by default. How could I do that?

The code:

```
from numpy import linspace
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.axes
import math


distance = [6, 56, 106, 156, 207, 257, 309, 257, 206, 154, 103, 52, 
            103, 153, 204, 254, 304, 354, 303, 252, 201, 150, 99, 47, 
            98, 149, 199, 249, 300, 350, 299, 248, 196, 145, 94, 42]

t = linspace(0, 6, 3291) 
t1 = linspace(0, 6, 2104)


plt.plot(t, local, "g", label="LOCAL")
plt.plot(t1, cpm, "r", label="CPM")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.fill_between(t, 0, local, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(t1, 0, cpm, facecolor='red', interpolate=False)

axes1 = plt.gca()
axes2 = axes1.twiny()
axes2.set_xticks(distance, minor=False)

plt.title("Object detection")
plt.xlabel("Time in Minutes")
plt.ylabel("Number of objects")
plt.show()
```

[image: How it prints right now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place the desired values on the axes, use the locator and formatter to place them. It can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) in the official reference.

```
from numpy import linspace
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.axes
import math
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

np.random.seed(20210210)
local = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=3291)
cpm = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=2104)

distance = [6, 56, 106, 156, 207, 257, 309, 257, 206, 154, 103, 52, 
            103, 153, 204, 254, 304, 354, 303, 252, 201, 150, 99, 47, 
            98, 149, 199, 249, 300, 350, 299, 248, 196, 145, 94, 42]
dis = [str(s) for s in distance]
pos = np.arange(0,len(dis))

t = linspace(0, 6, 3291) 
t1 = linspace(0, 6, 2104)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
plt.plot(t, local, "g", label="LOCAL")
plt.plot(t1, cpm, "r", label="CPM")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.fill_between(t, 0, local, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(t1, 0, cpm, facecolor='red', interpolate=False)

axes1 = plt.gca()
axes2 = axes1.twiny()
# axes2.set_xticks(distance, minor=False)
axes2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(pos))
axes2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(dis))
axes2.set_xlim(0,len(dis))

plt.title("Object detection")
plt.xlabel("Time in Minutes")
plt.ylabel("Number of objects")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.